# How do I increase the 255 character limit on the 'description' field for link library links?

Tags: plugins, links, description, library

My descriptions are being cut off and I need to increase this field to accomodate more text.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is [a ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17296) related to this issue. The short answer is there isn't a good fix. The core creates description fields that cannot hold more than 255 characters. Sorry :(

Answer (score -1):

I actually found the answer to my own question.

If you're using the "Link Library" Plugin, you can use the field "Link Large Description" instead of "Description" and it gives you much more space to work with for describing your links.  I don't know what the maximum is for this field.